# Does async operation in iOS create a new thread internally, and allocate task to it?

Tags: ios, swift

Does async operation in iOS, internally create a new thread, and allocate task to it ?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929317/how-can-i-display-all-the-threads-for-my-program-when-debug-in-xcode)

Answer (score 1):

An async operation is capable to internally create a new thread and allocate task to it. But in order for this to happen you need to run an async operation which creates a new thread and allocates task to it. Or in other words: There is no direct correlation.

I assume that by async you mean something like `DispatchQueue.main.async { <#code here#> }`. This does not create a new thread as main thread should already be present. How and why does this work can be (if oversimplified) explained with an array of operations and an endless loop which is basically what `RunLoop` is there for. Imagine the following:

```
Array<Operations> allOperations;

int main() {
    bool continueRunning = true;
    for(;continueRunning;) {
        allOperations.forEach { $0.run(); }
        allOperations.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And when you call something like `DispatchQueue.main.async` it basically creates a new operation and inserts it into `allOperations`. The same thread will eventually go into a new loop (within for-loop) and call your operation asynchronously. Again keep in mind that this is all over-simplified just to illustrate the idea behind all of it. You can from this also imagine how for instance timers work; the operation will evaluate if current time is greater then the one of next scheduled execution and if so it will trigger the operation on timer. That is also why timers can not be very precise since they depend on rest of execution and thread may be busy.

A new thread on the other hand may be spawned when you create a new queue `DispatchQueue(label: "Will most likely run on a new thread")`. When(if) exactly will a thread be made is not something that needs to be fixed. It may vary from implementations and systems being run on. The tool will only guarantee to perform what it is designed for but not how it will do it.

And then there is also `Thread` class which can generate a new thread. But the deal is same as for previous one; it might internally instantly create a new thread or it might do it later, lazily. All it guarantees is that it will work for it's public interface.

I am not saying that these things change over time, implementation or system they run on. I am only saying that they potentially could and they might have had.